# Encryption (AES)

Tags: android, security, cryptography, aes

I use AES algorithm for encrypt my data. When i encrypt 16 byte( one block) the result is 32 byte. I expect 16 byte but it generate 32 byte.
If i use my code in string format the result is same.
why?

My source code is

```
package chert.chert;

import chert.chert.R;
import chert.chert.SimpleCrypto;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChertActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView textView1;



    byte[] key=new byte[16];
    byte[] state=new byte[16];
    public SimpleCrypto Crypt = new SimpleCrypto(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int i;
        String ss,state_str,key_str;
        char c;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);




        //======================================================================================================================        

        state[0]=0x32;           state[1]=(byte) 0x88;  state[2]=0x31;          state[3]=(byte) 0xe0;
        state[4]=0x43;           state[5]=0x5a;         state[6]=0x31;          state[7]=0x37;
        state[8]=(byte) 0xf6;    state[9]=0x30;         state[10]=(byte) 0x98;  state[11]=0x07;
        state[12]=(byte) 0xa8;   state[13]=(byte) 0x8d; state[14]=(byte) 0xa2;  state[15]=0x34;


     //======================================================================================================================        

        key[0]=0x2b;           key[1]=0x28;                key[2]=(byte) 0xab;   key[3]=0x09;
        key[4]=0x7e;           key[5]=(byte) 0xae;         key[6]=(byte) 0xf7;   key[7]=(byte) 0xcf;
        key[8]=0x15;           key[9]=(byte) 0xd2;         key[10]=0x15;         key[11]=0x4f;
        key[12]=0x16;          key[13]=(byte) 0xa6;        key[14]=(byte) 0x88;  key[15]=0x3c;

      //======================================================================================================================        

        try {
            byte[] rawKey = Crypt.getRawKey(key);
            byte[] result = Crypt.encrypt(rawKey, state);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}







package chert.chert;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class SimpleCrypto {

    public SimpleCrypto(ChertActivity chertActivity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    public static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }


    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
    }
    public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length()/2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
    }

}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer after learning Cipher uses EBC mode encryption by default (!) rather than CBC mode (or something like it). However, this raises another point: You almost certainly want to override this default, since EBC is *not* secure by most reasonable formal definitions of the word. For example, someone intercepting EBC-mode encrypted messages can trivially tell if a message (or indeed, a block within a message) is repeated, or (in the absence of a properly implemented MAC) arbitrarily rearrange blocks. How harmful these things are depends on context, of course.

Comment: @Seth: ECB, not EBC. But we know what you mean :)

Answer (score 5):

If the length of the clear-text is a multiple of the block size, a whole new block is needed for padding according to [PKCS#5](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2127). Say your clear-text is 16 bytes. The cipher-text will take 32 bytes.

It is something like the following

```
CipherTextLength = (PlainTextLength / 16 + 1) * 16;
```

Comment: More specifically the default mode PKCS5Padding always adds *at least* one byte of padding, and always adds enough to round up to a multiple of the block length of 16 bytes.

Comment: You right. The length of Cipher =  (inserteddataLength/16 + 1) * 16; 
But there is a problem. If you enter 16 byte for encryption you earn 32 but you need 16 byte and these 32 byte isn,t your response.
If you enter 32 byte you earn 48 byte in result but you need only 32 byte.

Comment: @mosbate: when someone helps you with the relevant answer, please reward them by accepting their answer - that's the tick mark to the left of the answer.  (You also get a couple of points for accepting an answer.)